# How to use a large number of different textures with a shader?

Tags: directx11

I need to be able to compile an ".hlsl, .fx" shader in my DirectX app. The issue is that, with the code below, I can only specify 6 textures by their default path directory.

I don't want this - I want to be able to set one path to the directory containing all of my textures, then compile my shader and see the shader effect on all those 50 textures.

I am using DirectX June 2010 and using Direct3D11 and Visual Studio 2015.

```
#define NUM_TEXTURES 7
DETAIL_TESSELLATION_TEXTURE_STRUCT DetailTessellationTextures[NUM_TEXTURES + 
1] =
{
//    DiffuseMap              NormalHeightMap                 DisplayName,    
fHeightScale fBaseTextureRepeat fDensityScale fMeaningfulDifference
{ L"Textures\\rocks.jpg",    L"Textures\\rocks_NM_height.dds",  L"Rocks",       
10.0f,       1.0f,              25.0f,        2.0f/255.0f },
{ L"Textures\\stones.bmp",   L"Textures\\stones_NM_height.dds", L"Stones",      
5.0f,        1.0f,              10.0f,        5.0f/255.0f },
{ L"Textures\\wall.jpg",     L"Textures\\wall_NM_height.dds",   L"Wall",        
8.0f,        1.0f,              7.0f,         7.0f/255.0f },
{ L"Textures\\wood.jpg",     L"Textures\\four_NM_height.dds",   L"Four 
shapes", 30.0f,       1.0f,              35.0f,        2.0f/255.0f },
{ L"Textures\\concrete.bmp", L"Textures\\bump_NM_height.dds",   L"Bump",        
10.0f,       4.0f,              50.0f,        2.0f/255.0f },
{ L"Textures\\concrete.bmp", L"Textures\\dent_NM_height.dds",   L"Dent",        
10.0f,       4.0f,              50.0f,        2.0f/255.0f },
{ L"Textures\\wood.jpg",     L"Textures\\saint_NM_height.dds",  L"Saints" ,     
20.0f,       1.0f,              40.0f,        2.0f/255.0f },
{ L"",                       L"",                               L"Custom" ,     
5.0f,        1.0f,              10.0f,        2.0f/255.0f },
};
DWORD                               g_dwNumTextures = 0;
ID3D11ShaderResourceView*           
g_pDetailTessellationBaseTextureRV[NUM_TEXTURES+1];
ID3D11ShaderResourceView*           
g_pDetailTessellationHeightTextureRV[NUM_TEXTURES+1];
ID3D11ShaderResourceView*           
g_pDetailTessellationDensityTextureRV[NUM_TEXTURES+1];
ID3D11ShaderResourceView*           g_pLightTextureRV = NULL;
WCHAR                               
g_pszCustomTextureDiffuseFilename[MAX_PATH] = L"";
WCHAR                               
g_pszCustomTextureNormalHeightFilename[MAX_PATH] = L"";
DWORD                               g_bRecreateCustomTextureDensityMap  = 
false;
```

Comment: You should read [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx), [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/08/20/living-without-d3dx/), and see this [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/FX11) project.

Answer (score 1):

Normally your textures are loaded by the program and not by the shader directly. You then set the parameters of the GPU in some fashion such as:

```
m_texturePtr = m_effect->GetVariableByName("shaderTexture")->AsShaderResource();
```

which I grabbed from this tutorial as an example: http://rastertek.com/dx10tut48.html

The Graphics Card isn't made to randomly read from an unlimited numbers of textures at a time. Normally you will batch all the objects who require the same textures into the same call to the graphics library so that you don't have to keep swapping textures a lot.

If you have an object or collection of objects that use many different textures but need to be drawn in a single batch, then it's conventional to pre-combine those textures into a texture atlas or array texture. This is a single logical texture as far as the shader is concerned, and texture coordinates are used to pick out the particular texture you wanted from the larger collection.

---

In your case, simply make it so that before you render a model, you send the necessary texture to the graphics library first. The below is my code (C# monogame; using DX11 shaders)

```
public static void BatchDraw(Effect effect, bool clear)
        {   
            // walk through each texture type
            for (int j=0; j < (int)TextureType.MAX_TEXTURE; j++)
            {
                // derive the batch
                var currBatch = ObjectBatcher[j];
                
                // create a quad that is used for centering and sizing the texture
                var originalQuad = TextureSizes[j];

                // set the texture of the effect so that when we call draw, the correct type of texture is drawn
                //effect.Texture = TextureArray[j];
                effect.Parameters["colorTexture"].SetValue(TextureArray[j]);
                
                // for each of the "models", place it in 3-space and send the data to the graphics device
                var len = currBatch.PsuedoCount;
                for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
                {
                    AdjustModel(
                        // The offset of the texture to adjust the other vertices
                        originalQuad,
                        // The vertices that will be filled and then drawn
                        quadVertices, 
                        // The quad will be centered on this obj's position and spun by this obj's rotation
                        currBatch[i]);
                    
                    foreach (var pass in effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
                    { 
                        pass.Apply();
                    
                        // TODO: Look into the offset. Possibly a way to reduce my own computation?
                        myGD.DrawUserPrimitives(
                            // We’ll be rendering two triangles
                            PrimitiveType.TriangleList,
                            // The array of verts that we want to render
                            quadVertices,
                            // The offset, which is 0 since we want to start 
                            // at the beginning of the floorVerts array
                            0,
                            // The number of triangles to draw
                            2);
                    }
                    
                }

               
            }
        }
```

NOTE: I currently pass in each quad (my "models"), but instead I should pass in an array that describes all of those batched models at a time.